# Logging MySQL Failed authentication requests

Tags: mysql, authentication

I am having a few problems with a C++ application crashing, unfortunately I do not have the source to this, however I was wondering if its possible to turn on a logging function in MySQL that allows for it to show failed authentications requests...

Would someone be able to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/11/01/catching-erroneous-queries-without-mysql-proxy/) could help you.

Comment: Has someone edited out the link or something here ?